# To include payment option in a mini project

Tags: arrays

i want to include payment option in my mini project.
Online bus ticket booking is my project,i have done with php code.
I didnt tried anything for payment option.

Comment: I don't see the problem.  Could you narrow it down to a specific problem to solve, then ask it?  Thanks!